# why do my charAt function not working as i intended to?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying create a function to restrict the format accepted by `<input>` and when the format is satisfied, a `<div>` beside it will be hidden. (the format is I-xxxx-xxxx, whereas the first two characters is **I** and **-** and the seventh character is another **-**)

here's the breakdown my `<input>` and `<div>`

This is the function I am using to check the `<input>` and will hide the `<div>` if 
the format is satisfied.

```js
var referenceChecker = document.getElementById("reference_number").value;
var iChecker = referenceChecker.charAt(0);
var firstDashChecker = referenceChecker.charAt(1);
var lastDashChecker = referenceChecker.charAt(6);

function checkIfEmptyReferenceNumber(that) {
  if (that.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("ifEmptyReferenceNumberMessage").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    if (iChecker = "I" && firstDashChecker = "-" && lastDashChecker = "-") {
      document.getElementById("ifEmptyReferenceNumberMessage").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

```html
<input id="reference_number" onchange="checkIfEmptyReferenceNumber(this)"
 class="form-control" maxlength="11" type="text" ng-required="true" 
 ng-model="reference_number" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^I0-9-]/g, '')" />

<div id="ifEmptyReferenceNumberMessage" style="display: block;"><span style="color: red;">Reference Number Needed!</span></div>
```

I apologize but I cannot figure out where I was wrong.

Comment: Just try regex match. It works with both js and php ->> `/([I-]{2})(.{4})(-{1})(.{4})/gm`

Comment: changed the needed format from I-xxx-xxxx to I-xxxx-xxxx. sorry for that @Teemu

Comment: `(iChecker = "I" && firstDashChecker = "-" && lastDashChecker = "-")` but `=` is assignment, not comparision........

Comment: @CertainPerformance I already tried using `==` but it doesn't do anything

Comment: `referenceChecker` etc. should all be set inside the function, otherwise you will just get the initial value of the `reference_number` field.

Comment: @Adder wow! my initial tests is successful, thanks for that. do you mind if i tag you if something went wrong in the nearest future?

Comment: You are free to ping me, I get a red message flag every time you respond to me personally in this comments section

Answer (score 0):

How about a different approach? Not checking but instead enforcing the pattern:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");

input.onchange = input.oninput = input.onfocus = input.onkeydown = function(e){
  let digits = input.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
  if(e && e.type === "keydown" && e.key === "Backspace"){
    digits = digits.substr(0, digits.length-1);
  }
  let text = "I-" + digits.slice(0, 4).padEnd(4, "x") + "-" + digits.slice(4, 8).padEnd(4, "x");
  input.value = text;
  input.setSelectionRange(text.indexOf("x"), text.length);  
}

input.onchange();
```

```css
input:invalid {
  background: #FDD;
}

input:valid {
  background: #8F8;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="I-\d{4}-\d{4}"/>
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but someone in the comments solved my problem.